# Removing Slide Layouts from Presentation

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a following code for removing slide layout parts:

```
var presentation = output.PresentationPart;

var usedSlideLayouts = presentation.SlideParts.Select(it => it.SlideLayoutPart).ToList();
foreach (var sm in presentation.SlideMasterParts)
{
    var slideLayoutIds = sm.SlideMaster.SlideLayoutIdList.Elements<SlideLayoutId>().ToList();
    var slideLayoutParts = sm.SlideLayoutParts.ToList();

    var i = 0;
    foreach (var slp in slideLayoutParts)
    {
        var isUsed = usedSlideLayouts.Any(usl => usl == slp);

        if (!isUsed)
        {
            var slideLayoutId = slideLayoutIds[i];
            slideLayoutId.Remove();
            sm.DeletePart(slp);
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

When i save the presentation after running it my presentation is corrupted (needs to be restored before opening in power point).

From what I saw (by unzipping the pptx) this could be because of the fact that there is only one slide layout but it's internal URI is like 'slideLayout2.xml'. Is there a way to refresh that internal URI?

For anyone wondering I attached a powerpoint in this github issue:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/218

Comment: Are you able to upload the original file too?

Comment: @petelids i've uploaded it to github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `slideLayoutId` is the wrong one. The `SlideLayoutParts` are not necessarily returned in the same order as the `SlideLayoutId`s.

You can solve this by changing the line

```
var slideLayoutId = slideLayoutIds[i];
```

to

```
var slideLayoutId = slideLayoutIds.Where(sid => sid.RelationshipId == sm.GetIdOfPart(slp)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This picks the correct `slideLayoutId` based on the `RelationshipId`.

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved it. Such a noob mistake. I tried to use the GetIdOfPart, but I was using it on presentationPart and I was getting the:
'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.' exception, thus I used the index. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No worries @ŁukaszTrzewik - glad I could help.